# separate children with certain angle in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

Suppose a node has 10 children . How can I separate the children with an angle of (360 degree/no. of children ) 36 degree in force layout.Currently the children are placed randomly.

I have seen the example of collapsable force layout from 
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html

[image]

I have seen the documentation too. But not able to find any help.

Comment: You don't need the force layout if you know the positions of the nodes. Given the radius of the circle, you can compute them easily.